# How can I refresh my Reclycler adapter onDismiss?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-recyclerview

I have created a dialog from my Adapter, the dialog renames a record in a MySQL database, now once the data has been inserted, I call `dismiss();` but I also want to refresh the adapter after the dialog dismisses

Here's the relevant part of my code

**MyAdpater**

```
    private void showFragmentRenameWallet(RecyclerView.ViewHolder dataObjectHolder){
            RenameWalletDialog renameWalletFragment = new RenameWalletDialog();
 renameWalletFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager(), renameWalletFragment.getTag());
        }
```

**MyDialog**
    in my dialog after executing the volley request I dismiss using `dismiss();`

This is how i get the fragment reference in the dialog

```
MyFragment myFragment;
```

then

```
dismiss();
myFragment.onRefresh(); //produces null pointer
```

and in **MyFragment**

```
 @Override
   public void onRefresh() {
   loadData();
        }
```

So I created an instance of my fragment in my dialog and tried doing `myFragment.onRefresh();`, but I get a null pointer.

How can I properly do this?

Comment: You can do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @VarroxSystems `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Put it after you set your recycle view to the adapter ex:

mRecycleview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.notifyOnDataSetChanged

Comment: This will automatically refresh data when new data are added

Comment: @VarroxSystems This is just a bottom sheet dialog it just renames a record in the database, so i'm not actually adding new data

Comment: Sorry,i meant it changes any thing happened to the data in the recycle view even if it was a rename.

Comment: @VarroxSystems I cant access the recycler view adapter from the dialog, as it doesn't contain the recycler view, i can only access it from the fragment

Comment: Where you init your adapter in MyFragment right? and you put your context to adapter right? show me your code when you executing the volley done and dismiss

Comment: @hai yes, but i'm not trying to update the adapter from the fragment, rather im trying to update the adapter from the dialog class

Comment: @hai `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), datatList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: please help me update the code inside RenameWalletDialog, and how to you get reference instance of myFragment inside it?

Comment: This is how i get the fragment reference in the dialog? I don't see how you get fragment reference, help me update it. I want to know where you call myFragment.onRefresh() and how you get myFragment instance

Comment: hmm, you just declare MYFragment myFragment, and not assign it value, so it always null

Comment: show me your code you show MyFragment in your activity, I can fix it for you

Comment: @hai you were right, doing this `MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();` enables me access to the fragment, but i now get null pointer exceptions from properties in the fragment `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Comment: No no, it's wrong too, show me you code when you init MyFragment in your activity, you can get reference of it through FragmentManager of Activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212989/discussion-between-kennedy-and-hai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using `childFragmentManager` of MyFragment and pass it to Adapter
2. When show `renameWalletFragment` using `childFragmentManager` not `fragmentManager` of Context
3. Retrieve `myFragment` inside `RenameWalletDialog` by override `onCreate` and assign it by `myFragment = (MyFragment) parrentFragment`